# How to get png or jpeg or bmp pictures in wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython, wildcard

I want to search for png, jpeg and bmp pictures but it doesn't seems to work.

```
def onClick(self,Event):
        wildcard='PNG files (*.png)|*.png|'|'BMP files (*.bmp)|*.bmp|'|'JPEG files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|'
        openFileDialog = wx.FileDialog(self, "Open", "", "", wildcard,wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST)
        openFileDialog.ShowModal()
```

Here is the error and i don't know how to resolve it

```
wildcard='PNG files (*.png)|*.png|'|'BMP files (*.bmp)|*.bmp|'|'JPEG files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|'
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a string | string does not make sense. That means that

```
'something'|'something'
```

throws the exception above. All of your | characters should be a part of 
the wildcard string.

For just pngs use:

```
'PNGs (*.png)|*.png'
```

For gifs and jpegs use:

```
'Various image formats - png,jpg|*.png;*.jpg'
```

If you want to let the user choose:

```
'Various image formats|*.png;*.jpg|Just BMPs (*.bmp)|*.bmp'
```